# What are the tabs/spaces for in the Beowulf text

Tags: literature, anglo-saxons

[Here](http://ebeowulf.uky.edu/ebeo4.0/CD/main.html) and other places they have strange spacing as seen in the picture:

[image]

Wondering what it means and what the purpose of it / if it's necessary or has some significance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The spacing divides the '*half-lines*' of the poem. This is fundamental to [Old English metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_metre), where each line of the poem consists of two half-lines, connected by alliteration.

---

If you are interested, the [Electronic Beowulf edition](http://ebeowulf.uky.edu/ebeo4.0/CD/main.html), that you have linked in the question, has a section describing the [meter](http://ebeowulf.uky.edu/#optionaccesspoint-meter) of the poem.

> By clicking the Meter option, the student may choose to have tooltips for any or all of the five different prevailing metrical theories.

The meter option can be selected from the **Options** pane on the left of the viewer:

[image: meter option]

Comment: Wondering if the spacing (not the concept of the half-line) is a modern invention, because I'm looking at the tablet in the link to Beowulf and don't see any spaces there. Wondering if it could be "implemented" in other ways, such as a new indented line, or however you want. Or if it must be a larger space like that.

Comment: The spacing is simply a modern way of representing the half-lines in a printed text as a way of preserving the Old English metre. The original bards wouldn't have required it since it would have been memorised (and the earliest surviving manuscript (Cotton Vitellius A in the British Library), which may have been written almost 300 years after the poem was composed, doesn't even have breaks at the end of full-lines).

Comment: The surviving Old English manuscripts also don't always place word divisions in the same places modern texts place them.  See Roger Lass, _Historical Linguistics and Language Change_.